# Creating object connectors in Inkscape - how to get rid of gap?

Tags: inkscape

The connectors I create between two square boxes leave a gap. How do I fix that:

[image]

I connected the centers and was expecting the line start/end at the border of the shape, instead I get this gap.

Comment: And if I put another shape above the top square and connect, the line overlaps the shape? It looks like Inkscape thinks the box is slightly lower than it actually is.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Do you have a white stroke set on the top square?  I can't really replicate this problem. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I tried in a new iamge and there it looks fine. Maybe it's because the rectangles are grouped with text inside? I'll see if I can create a minimal example and post the svg.

Comment: If creating a new image fixed it, then maybe it was just a glitch.  Grouped items with text should be fine. I just tried it, and it still works.